# K is a basic elementary class if and only if both K and the complement of K are closed under ultraproducts and elementary equivalence.

Tags: logic, model-theory

I am reading this logic book and was trying to proof the second theorm :

**Theorem 13.3**: Let K be an arbitrary class of models. Then:

1. K is an elementary class if and only if K is closed under ultraproducts and elementary
   equivalence.
2. K is a basic elementary class if and only if both K and the complement of K are closed
   under ultraproducts and elementary equivalence.

At the end of the proof of (1) it states : (2) This follows easily from (1) and the compactness theorem. We leave the details for an
exercise.

This is a sketch of a proof of (2) but I didn't use compactness so I would like some feedback:

Assume K is a basic elementary class, then thehre is a sentense $\varphi$ of $\mathscr L$ such that K is the class of all models of $\varphi$.

1. **Closure under ultraproudcts:**
   Let {A$_i$} be a family of models in K, we will show that $\prod_DA_i$ is also in K. A$_i$ satisfies $\varphi$ (as K is the class of models satisfying $\varphi$) every element in the ultra product also satisfies $\varphi$ which implies that $\prod_DA_i$ is also in K hence K is closed under ultraproudcts.
   Let {B$_i$} be a family of models in K$^c$ since K is basic elemantry class exist a sentence $\varphi$ such that K is precisely the class of models satisfying $\varphi$, since B$_i$ is in K$^c$ for each i B$_i$ doesn't satisfey $\varphi$, now consider $\not$$\varphi$ since B$_i$ doesn't satisfey $\varphi$ it satisfies $\not$$\varphi$ which implies that $\prod_DB_i$ doesn't satisfey $\varphi$ hence $\prod_DB_i$ satisfies $\not$$\varphi$ hence K$^c$ is closed under ultraproducts.
2. **Closure under elementary equivalence:** Let A be a model in K$^c$ and let B be a model such that B$\equiv$A.B$\equiv$A hence B and A satisfies the same sentences, as A doesn't satisfey $\varphi$ also B doesn't satifey $\varphi$ hence B is in K$^c$ by definition hence K$^c$ is closed under elementary equivnalnce. (For K its the same argument...)

For the other $\to$ : if both K and K$^c$ are closed under ultraproudcts and elementary equivalnce, we can constract a sentence $\varphi$ such that K is the class of models of $\varphi$ and K$^c$ is the class of models of $\not$$\varphi$ thus K is a basic elemntary class and the proof is complete.

Comment: You should write $\neg \varphi$ (\lnot \varphi or \neg \varphi) instead of $\not\varphi$  (\not \varphi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implication "if both $K$ and the complement of $K$ are closed under ultraproducts and elementary equivalence, then $K$ is a basic elementary class" is the nontrivial one. You write:

> If both $K$ and $K^c$ are closed under ultraproducts and elementary equivalence, we can construct a sentence $\varphi$ such that $K$ is the class of models of $\varphi$ and $K^c$ is the class of models of $\lnot \varphi$. Thus $K$ is a basic elementary class and the proof is complete.

It should be obvious to you that this is no proof at all! "We can construct a sentence $\varphi$..." *How?*

... well, this is probably where you need to use compactness...

*Hint:* Suppose $K$ and $K^c$ are both closed under ultraproducts and compactness. By (1), $K$ and $K^c$ are both elementary classes. Suppose $T_1$ is a theory axiomatizing $K$ and $T_2$ is a theory axiomatizing $K^c$. What can you say about the theory $T_1\cup T_2$? Remember, your goal is to replace $T_1$ by a single sentence axiomatizing $K$.

---

Your proof of the other direction looks fine (though the writing and spelling and grammar are pretty sloppy). But I want to point out that this direction really does follow from (1) with no extra work. Assume $K$ is a basic elementary class. Then $K^c$ is also basic elementary (since if $\varphi$ is a sentence axiomatizing $K$, then $\lnot \varphi$ axiomatizes $K^c$). In particular, both $K$ and $K^c$ are elementary classes. So by (1), both $K$ and $K^c$ are closed under ultraproducts and elementary equivalence.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! would u say what I am trying to proof is the same as  A class K of L-structures is a finitely axiomatizable elementary class if and only if both K and it's complement are closed under ultraproducts and isomorphism? Cause I saw a proof u did and I understood that

Comment: @Giladbe10 That result is stronger (since it's hypotheses are weaker: a class closed under elementary equivalence is obviously closed under isomorphism, but not conversely). And the proof uses a big hammer: the Keisler-Shelah theorem, which is decidedly non-trivial to prove.

Comment: I am aware of Keisler-Shelah theorem , then based on your proof for A class K of L-structures is a finitely axiomatizable elementary class if and only if both K and it's complement are closed under ultraproducts and isomorphism I can claim that since elementary equvialance are closed under isomorphism then the sentence I was trying to proof is correct? I am just trying to understand at this point in order to proof it my self, for some reason I do understand your hint but can't connect it to a finaly answer, yet the other proof I understood completly...(which I suppose the hint is conntect to)

Comment: Yes, this argument (Proof of 2 in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4335301/7062)) answers your question. But note that the bulk of the argument is just showing that $K$ and $K^c$ are elementary (which in your context, you can appeal to (1) for, as in the hint I wrote above). The last step, i.e. using compactness to show that $K$ and $K^c$ are finitely axiomatizable, is just the very last paragraph of my answer in the link.

Comment: I really appreciate all the help brother!